# Hide price if over £100K in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like the price to be hidden if it is over a certain threshold ie £100,000 in woocommerce.

Also if it is left blank, or set to zero too. Although those conditions are answered well elsewhere.

Comment: Want to Hide Products, When Price is Zero? Or only price on the product?

Answer (score 0):

When the Product is not available OR out of stock then many store owners make the price ” 0 ” , It gives an expression to the user that Product is not available.

So if you want to Hide Products, When Price is Zero, Add the following Code in the end of the functions file -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'themelocation_product_query' );
function themelocation_product_query( $q ){
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'       => '_price',
                    'value'     => 0,
                    'compare'   => '>'
                );
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Open your shop page you can see the product with price zero is not shown in the products.

Comment: Hi Amritosh
I want to show the product, but want to hide the price and replace it with P.O.A.
Thanks